# Postsharp not compiling in release mode

Tags: postsharp

I'm using Postsharp express and everything is working properly when I'm using it in debug mode (x86).
When I set it to Release mode the compiler cannot find this attribute `SafeForDependencyAnalysis`

and I get an error saying:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PostSharp' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The only thing I changed was switching from Debug to Release mode. How can I fix that?

I'm using the latest version of Postsharp 4.2.22.0

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add PostSharp to your project by installing NuGet packages? You would need PostSharp and PostSharp.Patterns.Model packages installed for the feature you're using. Also, if you look at *.csproj file, can you find the PostSharp references in the common references ItemGroup? Are the HintPaths correct?

Comment: Yes, I used NuGet. I'll check the references you mentioned on Monday. I find it very strange that the problem happens only when I built the app in release mode.

Comment: I had similar wiered issue. I restarted Visual Studio and at some point it worked...